# Using @WebAppConfiguration with multiple web context configurations

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

I got multiple different web context configurations in my Spring MVC application, defined via Servlet mappings in the web.xml (api-servlet.xml und web-servlet.xml)

When I create a Integration Test using the @WebAppConfiguration annotation it seems to load all of my web context configurations which leads to the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler 'myService' to URL path [/refresh]: There is already handler of type [class com.troii.timr.api.APIController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eaca0afa] mapped.
```

This happens because the URL /refresh is normally configured in two different web context configurations with different URL prefixes.

Is there a way to configure which web context config is used for my migration test?